# I want to compare arrays and put together the same values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am using typescript.
I want to create a new array that compares the code values of the arrays groupA and groupB and adds same:true to the same codes and same:false to the ones that are not the same.   I want to combine the same codes into one.
I want to create an array like newGroup.

```
"groupA": [
    {
      "code": "aaaaa",
      "name": "group1",
      "editable": false,
    },
    {
      "code": "bbbb",
      "name": "group2",
      "editable": false,
    },
    {
      "code": "cccc",
      "name": "group3",
      "editable": false,
    },
    {
      "code": "dddd",
      "name": "group4",
      "editable": false,
    },
    {
      "code": "eeee",
      "name": "group5",
      "editable": false,
    },
  ] 


"groupB": [
    {
      "code": "aaaaa",
      "name": "group1",
    },
    {
      "code": "bbbb",
      "name": "group2",
    },
  ]
```

```
"newGroup": [
    {
      "code": "aaaaa",
      "name": "group1",
      "editable": false,
      "same":true,
    },
    {
      "code": "bbbb",
      "name": "group2",
      "editable": false,
      "same":true,
    },
    {
      "code": "cccc",
      "name": "group3",
      "editable": false,
      "same":false,
    },
    {
      "code": "dddd",
      "name": "group4",
      "editable": false,
      "same":false,
    },
    {
      "code": "eeee",
      "name": "group5",
      "editable": false,
      "same":false,
    },
  ]
```

Comment: What have you tried on your own already? Do you need just these two arrays specifically, or are you looking for a more general solution?

Comment: What does `same: true` mean? Like, what if `groupB` would contain `{ code: "aaaaa", name: "foo bar" }` or `{ code: "asdf", name: "group1" }`? What would be the results in these cases? Basically what's the logic to determine what "same" objects are?

Answer (score 1):

```js
const groupA =[
    {
      "code": "aaaaa",
      "name": "group1",
      "editable": false,
    },
    {
      "code": "bbbb",
      "name": "group2",
      "editable": false,
    },
    {
      "code": "cccc",
      "name": "group3",
      "editable": false,
    },
    {
      "code": "dddd",
      "name": "group4",
      "editable": false,
    },
    {
      "code": "eeee",
      "name": "group5",
      "editable": false,
    }
  ] 


const groupB=[
    {
      "code": "aaaaa",
      "name": "group1",
    },
    {
      "code": "bbbb",
      "name": "group2",
    }
  ] ;
  const newGroup = groupA.map(a => {
    const found = groupB.find(b=> (b.code===a.code && b.name===a.name));
    return {...a,...found,same:!!found};
  })
  console.log(newGroup);
```

Comment: Why `reduce` if you're mapping `groupA` 1:1 to a result `const newGroup = groupA.map(a => { const found = groupB.find(b => (b.code === a.code && b.name === a.name)); return { ...a, ...found, same: !!found }; });`

Comment: That makes more sense.